# how to know the available methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python. This question might duplicate.

How to know the methods of lists. After search in google, its come to know there are more than 10 methods like append,insert , ,. is there any command/syntax to know the available methods.
lists is for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print(dir(list))` will give you the available methods on a class.

or `help(list)` in the REPL for nicer formatting, as suggested by @DeepSpace

Comment: or `help(list)` in the REPL for nicer formatting